# Regular expression to replace a string, but not values assigned to a Scalar

Tags: regex, perl

Please do pardon me if my question sounds a bit awkward. I am looking for a regex which will replace line numbers in perl source file without affecting values assigned to scalars.

I think below will make my question a little bit clearer. Say I have a perl source which looks like this:

```
1. $foo = 2.4;
2. print $foo;
```

I would like a regular expression to replace those line numbers `(1. 2. etc..)` without affecting value assigned to scalars, and so in this case `$foo`.

Thanks

Comment: it sounds like a basic question, did you search ?

Comment: Well, what is the difference between a line number and an scalar assignation? If you say "line numbers always are at the start of a line, and scalar assignations are not", then the regexp becomes quite easy.. `s/^\d//;` will remove all numbers only at the start of a line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within a perl regex you can use the caret symbol `^` to represent the start of a line. `$` represents the end of a line. These are known as anchors.

So to find a number `\d` at the beginning of a line (only) you can search for

```
/^\d+/
```

If you wanted to remove those numbers you can "replace" them with nothing, as in

```
s/^\d+//g
```

You also want to include the dot after the number, so you might try
;

```
/^\d+./
```

But in regex a dot represents "any character" so you will need to escape the dot to have it interpreted literally

```
/^\d+\./
```

The caret symbol `^` also serves double-duty in character sets (it negates them), I only mention this as it is a common source of confusion when learning regex.

```
/[^\d]/   # Match characters that are not digits
```

Answer (score 5):

anchor your regexp to the start of the line:

to remove the numbers:

```
perl -p -i.bak -e's{^\d+\. }{}' myperl
```